# Rails - form for child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I'm little bit confused about Rails forms. I know there are nested forms, but I need something else. I think.

So, I have models floor and room. Every floor have many rooms, and every room belongs to one floor. (1-N association)

On every floor I have button to add new room. (opens modal for form).

How can I make form for that room with association to floor?

---

View:

```
<% @floors.each do |floor| %>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title"><b> <%= floor.name %></b></span>
      <div class="row">
      <% floor.rooms.each do |room| %>
          <div class="input-field col s3 l3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title"><b> <%= room.name %></b></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end unless floor.rooms.nil?%>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" style="float: right" href="#modal2">Add room</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Models:

```
class Floor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :floor
end
```

Controller:

```
  def floor_params
    params.require(:floor).permit(:name, :room_attributes => [:name])
  end
```

Comment: In which view file you have that code for adding rooms to floor?

Comment: @Pavan floors/index, and I want to make room forms there.

Comment: Note that `floor.rooms` is never going to be `nil`, because it will always return an ActiveRecord association of some kind. If the intent is to check if a `floor` has no `rooms`, you should use `floor.rooms.empty?`. Or it may be more clear to write `if floor.rooms.present?`.

Comment: Although this is not a solution, your current `floor_params` are at least faulty since it's an *has_many* association. `room_attributes: [:name]` should be `rooms_attributes: [:name]` (notice the plural form of room(s))

Comment: thanks everyone on your advices, I will implement them to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to create rooms for an existing floor, then you can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Instead you can use *nested resources* with `form_for` to create a room for that floor like so

```
<%= form_for [floor, @room] do |f| %>
  --- code---
<% end %>
```

In `floor_controller#index` add `@room = Room.new` and include the below in `routes.rb`

```
#routes.rb
resources :floors do
  resources :rooms, only: [:create]
end
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thank you!